# Problem using 0x polygon API - 500 - reason: 'relation "valid_signed_orders_v4" does not exist'

Tags: polygon, 0x, external-api, exchange-api

I am attempting to use the 0x Orderbook API for Polygon. I think there might be an issue with the API though, as whilst I remember it previously working, it doesn't seem to be anymore.

I'm getting the following response with status code 500:
`{'reason': 'relation "valid_signed_orders_v4" does not exist'}`

This is leading me to suspect theres something wrong going on when the backend queries the database. Not sure though, im pretty new to 0x.

The following is my request:
`requests.get('https://polygon.api.0x.org/orderbook/v1/orders')` without adding any params or headers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting! It should be fixed now